# How to move Site Collection to different Path in same Web Application?

Tags: site-collection, backup, restore

I know the process involves [backing up the site collection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748617.aspx). And [restoring](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748655.aspx) it afterwards.

I'm looking for specific steps on the restore process.

I have a site collection at the root of a web application: `http://myServer:40123/` I now want to move this root site collection to a different path, e.g. `http://myServer:40123/sites/myOldRoot/`, so that I can have a new/different root site collection.

What are the steps I need to do? Will I need to create this site collection beforehand or will `Restore-SPSite` do everything for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Import-SPWeb`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx)/[`Export-SPWeb`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  Cmdlets to can move site collection as a subsite.

**Export-SPWeb CMDLET**

```
Export-SPWeb http://site -Path "site export.cmp"
```

**Import-SPWeb CMDLET**

```
Import-SPWeb http://site -Path export.cmp -UpdateVersions Overwrite
```

> **Note:** `Restore-SPSite` is not working to move Top site collections to subsite.

Comment: check also [Move Site Collection from one Web Application to another](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/10/28/how-to-move-site-collection-from-one-webapplication/)

Answer (score 5):

You can use PowerShell to do that, check [Restore-SPSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607788.aspx) cmdlet.

```
Restore-SPSite http://server_name/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak
```

Comment: That is incorrect. I cannot restore a top-level web site to a subsite.

Comment: Hmm, just tried it again and it works. I used top site collection and restored it to same web application as a sub site collection. Did you receive an error or what?

Comment: *"Restore-SPSite:The specified URL is not a top level Web site. The backup and restore operations work only for top-level Web sites."*. See this post for more information: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sharepoint2010setup/thread/7bd1f735-35c0-4397-870e-2957f365c30d - I got it to work now by using `Export-SPWeb` and `Import-SPWeb` - maybe you can edit your answer so I have something to accept ;-)

Comment: Are you trying to move Site Collection (SPSite) or just a single Site (SPWeb), your question is about moving (restoring) entire site collection to another location, while you comment is about moving a single site, so I am bit confused here :)

Comment: Sharepoint and naming of things... I want to move the site collection (SPSite) located at the URL above. This site collection contains only a root web anyways, so in this case my SPSite == SPWeb. In any case: You cannot restore a backed up root site collection to another sub-path. You can only restore it to a root again.

Answer (score -2):

I ran into this the other day.

If you are using the url format of h`ttp://sharepointserver/sitename` then you'll want to visit Define Managed Paths and add the sitename.